# Join 2 pandas dataframes by adding rows with the same index

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling to join two dataframes by index (I've made column FileName an index for both tables) which look like this:

Table 1

| FileName | Transcriber | Transcription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 612_000002.wav | 100% (80/80) | Are we starting off? |
| 612_000002.wav | 100% (50/50) | shall we starting on |
| 612_000002.wav | 100% (2/2) | fast mode |
| 612_000002.wav | 100% (258/259) | Go and start it up |
| 612_000002.wav | 100% (20/20) | Are we starting off? |
| 612_000003.wav | 100% (258/259) | here we go, hey well woah woah woah |
| 612_000003.wav | 100% (23/23) | evening gulf air |
| 612_000003.wav | 100% (32/32) | And as the 1st group reached the bottom of the... |
| 612_000003.wav | 100% (80/80) | Happy to go off here, woah woah woah |
| 612_000003.wav | 100% (10/10) | Go boom we'll just |

Table 2 is similar and looks like this:

| FileName | Transcriber | Transcription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 612_000002.wav | Quartznet | there was not inl |
| 612_000002.wav | Transducer_M | don't start again |
| 612_000002.wav | Transducer_L | do we start again |
| 612_000003.wav | Transducer_L | anything off yeah i'm willing we'll just |
| 612_000003.wav | Transducer_S | having gone here on will and wolf is |

So I've looked into concat, merge, and join. But they don't seem to yield the output I am looking for. What I would like to have is all values from both tables for filename1, all values for filename2 and etc. Basically, adding rows from table2 to table1. Is there any way around it?
Thank you <3

Comment: thank you, @DeveshShukla. I've tried it, but I get hundreds of duplicates plus columns Transcriber_x, Transcription_x, Transcriber_y, Transcription_y

Comment: So what should the output look like, given the examples?

Comment: pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates() this will help?

Comment: all done! thank you, everyone, for your inputs! pd.concat worked indeeed, just had to sort the values afterwards. Easy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates()
```